# How to resolve null-valued expression error

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a PowerShell script (copied from Net) that would be executed using SQL Server Agent Job. This script will read an excel and create a CSV file from it.
I do not have excel installed on the machine running this script hence using this method.

Code is :

```
$strFileName = "C:\xxxx\yyyy.xlsx"
$strSheetName = 'MasterCalendar$'
$strProvider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
$strDataSource = "Data Source = $strFileName"
$strExtend = "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';"
$strQuery = "Select [Machine_ID],[1469] from [$strSheetName]"

$objConn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("$strProvider;$strDataSource;$strExtend")
$sqlCommand = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand($strQuery)
$sqlCommand.Connection = $objConn
$objConn.open()

$da = New-Object system.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter($sqlCommand)
$dt = New-Object system.Data.datatable
[void]$da.fill($dt)

$dataReader.close()
$objConn.close()

$dt 

$dt | Export-Csv C:\xxxx\data.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

When executed through SQL server agent it is throwing below error :

*Message Executed as user: Test\User1. A job step received
an error at line 17 in a PowerShell script. The corresponding line is
'$dataReader.close()  '. Correct the script and reschedule the job.
The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'You cannot call a
method on a null-valued expression.  '.  Process Exit Code -1.  The
step failed.*

I am new to scripting and PowerShell, unable to understand the issue as this exact code is running fine on my machine but starts throwing error when executed through SQL server agent job.

Comment: It doesn't even look like you create an object called $dataReader?  Hence you are trying to close an object that doesn't exist (and $dataReader is therefore null)?  Just remove the line....

Comment: Thanks a ton @Captain_Planet, it worked after I removed the line.